# Getting background image to resize to page size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm looking for a way to get the background image to resize to the page size (Note: not just the browser window size). For example say the page loads, and the page height necessitates a scroll. Is there a way of resizing the background image taking into account the content below the visible portion of the screen?

Comment: try this plugin [`bgstretcher`](http://www.ajaxblender.com/bgstretcher-2-jquery-stretch-background-plugin-updated.html)

Comment: This plug-in acts on an img tag (rather than using background-image and background-size) and appears to support IE7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using CSS3 is'nt a problem:

```
$('body').css('background-size', document.width+'px '+document.height+'px');​
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UpAv2/)

Comment: Then you'll probably have to set the bakground as a seperate img element and not in CSS. and set it's size to 100%, that should work in most browsers.

Comment: I wasn't able to get the above code to work in FF or Chrome on a standalone web page (haven't tried it in fiddle), but the following worked: `$('body').css({'backgroundSize': $(document).width() + 'px ' + $(document).height() + 'px'});`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't require support for IE8 or earlier:

```
body {
    background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
    background-size: auto 100%;
}
```

This maintains the aspect ratio of the image, so the image won't necessarily cover the entire width of the page.